# How to get nearest locations by coords using Laravel or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, proximity

I have a locations table that has latitude and longitude

I have a JavaScript event that register the clicked coords, that coords are saved on coords variable.

Then, I'm using axios to get a list of nearest coords but so far I make it return the whole list of my database table because I don't know how to list all the locations close to the received parameter

For example, in my JavaScript

```
    let franchiseListRoute = '{{route('franchises.list')}}' + '/' + JSON.stringify(coords);
    axios.get(franchiseListRoute)
        .then((response) => {
            response.data.forEach((item) => {
                console.log(item);
                let latlng = item.latlng.split(',');
                new L.Marker(latlng).addTo(map);
                console.log(item.name, item.is_available, item.latitude, item.longitude);
            });
        });
```

currently, the response is all the locations table

this is my laravel function

```
public function getFranchises($latlng = null)
{
    return Franchise::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
}
```

What is the better and Optimus way using Javascript or Laravel (faster for the final user) to get the nearest 800m. locations list?

Comment: I think you're asking for some sort of geometry operation within your database. I know nothing about Laravel, but there appears to be spatial extensions for it:  https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial

Answer (score 0):

solved using this query

```
public function getFranchises($latlng = null)
{
    if ($latlng){
        $latitude = json_decode($latlng)[0];
        $longitude = json_decode($latlng)[1];
        $radiusInMeters = 800;
        
        return Franchise::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6371000 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitude.') )
        * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$longitude.') )
        + sin( radians('.$latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
            ->having('distance', '<', $radiusInMeters)
            ->orderBy('distance')
            ->get();
    }
}
```